# React- Props don't update when changing their state through the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

The props on the 'GameState' component do not update correctly after changing their state from, they are always one iteration behind what the actual value of the state is as shown in the GIF and the sate is always one iteration behind when I try console.logging it too

[image]

```
import GameInfo from './components/GameInfo';
import GameState from './components/GameState';
import InputField from './components/InputField';
import StartButton from './components/StartButton';
import TheWord from './components/TheWord';
import WordsBox from './components/WordsBox';

function App() {
  const [currentDifficulty, setCurrentDifficulty] = useState({
    time: 7,
    wordCount: 15,
  });

  const changeDifficultyHandler = (difficulty) => {
    setCurrentDifficulty(difficulty);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        Type Master
      </header>
      <main>
        <GameInfo onChangeDifficulty={changeDifficultyHandler} />
        <TheWord />
        <InputField />
        <StartButton />
        <WordsBox />
        <GameState difficulty={currentDifficulty} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const GameState = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Time Left: {props.difficulty.time} Seconds</div>
      <div>Score: 0 From {props.difficulty.wordCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameState;
```

expected values:

```
  const levels = {
    Easy: {
      time: 7,
      wordCount: 15,
    },
    Normal: {
      time: 5,
      wordCount: 25,
    },
    Hard: {
      time: 3,
      wordCount: 30,
    },
  };
```

Code at the GameInfo component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const GameInfo = (props) => {
  const levels = {
    Easy: {
      time: 7,
      wordCount: 15,
    },
    Normal: {
      time: 5,
      wordCount: 25,
    },
    Hard: {
      time: 3,
      wordCount: 30,
    },
  };

  const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState(levels.Easy);

  const changeDifficultyHandler = (event) => {
    setDifficulty(levels[event.target.value]);
    props.onChangeDifficulty(difficulty);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      You Are Playing On The{' '}
      <span>
        [
        <select onChange={changeDifficultyHandler}>
          <option value='Easy'>Easy</option>
          <option value='Normal'>Normal</option>
          <option value='Hard'>Hard</option>
        </select>
        ]
      </span>{' '}
      Difficulity & You Have{' '}
      <span className='text-main font-poppins font-bold'>
        [ {difficulty.time} ]
      </span>{' '}
      Seconds To Type The Word.
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameInfo;
```

Comment: `<GameInfo onChangeDifficulty={changeDifficultyHandler} />` Can you show your code at `onChangeDifficulty` and select button in <GameInfo/> ?

Comment: Done, edited the queston to include the code for the GameInfo Component
and here's a quick codesandbox minus the styles of the app as I am using tailwind to style this: 
[(https://rc5s1n.csb.app/](https://rc5s1n.csb.app/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set state is async, so in `changeDifficultyHandler`, `difficulty` is still referencing the old value because it hasn't updated yet. A simple fix would be changing `props.onChangeDifficulty(difficulty)` to `props.onChangeDifficulty(levels[event.target.value])`.

That said, storing the same state in two places isn't best practice. Why not just keep the state in `App` and pass it to `GameInfo` as a prop like `<GameInfo onChangeDifficulty={changeDifficultyHandler} difficulty={currentDifficulty} />`?

Answer (score 0):

First import `useEffect` to your file

```
import {useEffect} from "react"
```

then,

Add this to your first code and try,

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [props.onChangeDifficulty(difficulty)]);
```

You have add this in your `GameInfo.jsx`.

Comment: I already tried that, even when having useEffect the console.log inside it is always one iteration late,  note that the value for currentDifficulty is coming from another component through a handler function passed as props which brings the value to the App component to be stored in the currentDifficulty state, then passed down to yet another component to show the change in the UI, maybe this scenario requires a different workaround than the useEffect hook?

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox of this?

Comment: here's a quick codesandbox minus the styles of the app as I am using tailwind to style this: 
[(https://rc5s1n.csb.app/](https://rc5s1n.csb.app/)

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, thank you.

Comment: Could you explain though what exactly does the empty useEffect exactly do? because I cannot fully make sense out of it

Comment: Calling a function from the dependency array is not correct.